# Will I get UK tourist visa?

Tags: visas, uk, applications, itineraries

My intended date of travel to the UK was this weekend. I mentioned the date in all documents along with tickets, but I haven't gotten my visa yet.
It's been 6 working days and I understand it takes 15.

Will they issue me a visa when my travel date and entire itinerary was planned from this weekend till the 30th? The intended travel date has already passed, will I still get the visa?

Answer (score 2):

The UK specifically states that evidence of travel bookings is not required when applying for a visitor visa (see section 4 https://www.gov.uk/government/publications/visitor-visa-guide-to-supporting-documents/guide-to-supporting-documents-visiting-the-uk)

Therefore, IMHO, in theory if you qualify for the visa and the trip is purely for tourism the fact that the intended travel date has passed should not matter (although if you have booked your travel it does show that you haven’t properly understood the documentary requirements). On the other hand, if your entire trip was built around a specific premise eg going to a wedding, or a concert/conference etc, or there’s a perceived restriction on your travel dates such as permission for leave from your employer for the planned dates only, or needing to return by a certain date for your studies, it might make a difference. But no-one can answer for certain.

Comment: Booking travel before being granted the visa in no way indicates that you've not understood the requirements. Somebody might be confident that they will get the visa and book anyway. Or they might be doing everything at short notice, hoping that the visa will be granted before the date of travel, but not wanting to have to buy tickets at the very last minute.